# PostgreSQL query in WAIT event IO - DataFileRead for more than 24 hours

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am facing an issue with some queries which use to take few minutes are now stuck in Wait Event - IO - DataFileRead for more than 24 hours and still did not complete.

```
SELECT rpsa.role_player_address_id, rpsa.change_detection_hash_key,standardized_address_partition_key, 
 rpsa.latest_source_provided_record_id,rpsa.row_modified_tmst, rpsa.row_created_tmst, 
 rpsa.row_created_identifier_txt,rpsa.row_modified_identifier_txt 
 FROM (select distinct role_player_id from 
 eval_source_record_1213_1214) esp 
 inner join 
 midas_user.role_player_address rpa on rpa.role_player_id=esp.role_player_id 
 inner join
 midas_user.role_player_standardized_address rpsa on rpsa.role_player_address_id=rpa.role_player_address_id and 
 rpsa.role_player_id=esp.role_player_id
```

role_player_standardized_address and role_player_address are partitioned tables with 256 partitions based on role_player_id

Since the query is not complete, I am not able to share EXPLAIN ANALYZE output. I ran EXPLAIN PLAN and sharing it here: had to remove additional partitions from the EXPLAIN PLAN to be able to post the question here.

```
QUERY PLAN
Merge Join  (cost=129306330.48..1464710850.13 rows=3184844130974 width=125)
  Merge Cond: ((rpa.role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id) AND (rpa.role_player_address_id = rpsa.role_player_address_id))
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=119.68..59694113.20 rows=344002429 width=16)
        Sort Key: rpa.role_player_id, rpa.role_player_address_id
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_1_pkey on role_player_address_p_1 rpa_1  (cost=0.43..129926.36 rows=1317041 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_2_pkey on role_player_address_p_2 rpa_2  (cost=0.43..459984.78 rows=1398431 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_3_pkey on role_player_address_p_3 rpa_3  (cost=0.43..459333.47 rows=1400130 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_4_pkey on role_player_address_p_4 rpa_4  (cost=0.43..452906.33 rows=1400663 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_5_pkey on role_player_address_p_5 rpa_5  (cost=0.43..458801.67 rows=1401247 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_6_pkey on role_player_address_p_6 rpa_6  (cost=0.43..455839.18 rows=1399072 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_7_pkey on role_player_address_p_7 rpa_7  (cost=0.43..458477.59 rows=1404475 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_8_pkey on role_player_address_p_8 rpa_8  (cost=0.43..48906.43 rows=1329200 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_9_pkey on role_player_address_p_9 rpa_9  (cost=0.43..48523.24 rows=1326054 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_10_pkey on role_player_address_p_10 rpa_10  (cost=0.43..130009.62 rows=1317427 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_11_pkey on role_player_address_p_11 rpa_11  (cost=0.43..459733.15 rows=1397382 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_12_pkey on role_player_address_p_12 rpa_12  (cost=0.43..456642.14 rows=1402609 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_13_pkey on role_player_address_p_13 rpa_13  (cost=0.43..461518.79 rows=1401418 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_14_pkey on role_player_address_p_14 rpa_14  (cost=0.43..445616.33 rows=1397452 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_15_pkey on role_player_address_p_15 rpa_15  (cost=0.43..449683.48 rows=1397304 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_16_pkey on role_player_address_p_16 rpa_16  (cost=0.43..455339.85 rows=1402631 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_17_pkey on role_player_address_p_17 rpa_17  (cost=0.43..502353.94 rows=1375534 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_18_pkey on role_player_address_p_18 rpa_18  (cost=0.43..456893.51 rows=1400294 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_19_pkey on role_player_address_p_19 rpa_19  (cost=0.43..450850.40 rows=1395119 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_20_pkey on role_player_address_p_20 rpa_20  (cost=0.43..462972.63 rows=1403847 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_21_pkey on role_player_address_p_21 rpa_21  (cost=0.43..460128.14 rows=1397467 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_22_pkey on role_player_address_p_22 rpa_22  (cost=0.43..460115.93 rows=1399672 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_23_pkey on role_player_address_p_23 rpa_23  (cost=0.43..462159.58 rows=1397342 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_24_pkey on role_player_address_p_24 rpa_24  (cost=0.43..461104.27 rows=1398968 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_25_pkey on role_player_address_p_25 rpa_25  (cost=0.43..451323.51 rows=1397908 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_26_pkey on role_player_address_p_26 rpa_26  (cost=0.43..460426.17 rows=1400999 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_27_pkey on role_player_address_p_27 rpa_27  (cost=0.43..453272.20 rows=1398965 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_28_pkey on role_player_address_p_28 rpa_28  (cost=0.43..457630.54 rows=1393256 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_29_pkey on role_player_address_p_29 rpa_29  (cost=0.43..461254.64 rows=1400438 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_30_pkey on role_player_address_p_30 rpa_30  (cost=0.43..451203.61 rows=1402670 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_31_pkey on role_player_address_p_31 rpa_31  (cost=0.43..462472.96 rows=1398159 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_32_pkey on role_player_address_p_32 rpa_32  (cost=0.43..452118.15 rows=1399050 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_33_pkey on role_player_address_p_33 rpa_33  (cost=0.43..453552.66 rows=1398539 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_34_pkey on role_player_address_p_34 rpa_34  (cost=0.43..467160.10 rows=1402125 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_35_pkey on role_player_address_p_35 rpa_35  (cost=0.43..451414.72 rows=1402211 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_36_pkey on role_player_address_p_36 rpa_36  (cost=0.43..442885.09 rows=1375269 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_37_pkey on role_player_address_p_37 rpa_37  (cost=0.43..457090.26 rows=1400295 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_38_pkey on role_player_address_p_38 rpa_38  (cost=0.43..457697.76 rows=1399844 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_39_pkey on role_player_address_p_39 rpa_39  (cost=0.43..454290.67 rows=1404019 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_40_pkey on role_player_address_p_40 rpa_40  (cost=0.43..449456.07 rows=1400265 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_41_pkey on role_player_address_p_41 rpa_41  (cost=0.43..453633.28 rows=1401545 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_42_pkey on role_player_address_p_42 rpa_42  (cost=0.43..451464.10 rows=1401315 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_43_pkey on role_player_address_p_43 rpa_43  (cost=0.43..122241.21 rows=1319716 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_44_pkey on role_player_address_p_44 rpa_44  (cost=0.43..458728.72 rows=1397838 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_45_pkey on role_player_address_p_45 rpa_45  (cost=0.43..448967.72 rows=1398055 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_46_pkey on role_player_address_p_46 rpa_46  (cost=0.43..464434.59 rows=1403131 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_47_pkey on role_player_address_p_47 rpa_47  (cost=0.43..457162.29 rows=1402287 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_48_pkey on role_player_address_p_48 rpa_48  (cost=0.43..439329.41 rows=1367007 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_49_pkey on role_player_address_p_49 rpa_49  (cost=0.43..459553.94 rows=1397435 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_50_pkey on role_player_address_p_50 rpa_50  (cost=0.43..453418.83 rows=1400993 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_51_pkey on role_player_address_p_51 rpa_51  (cost=0.43..454826.39 rows=1399985 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_52_pkey on role_player_address_p_52 rpa_52  (cost=0.43..493102.77 rows=1372966 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_53_pkey on role_player_address_p_53 rpa_53  (cost=0.43..459346.90 rows=1399940 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_54_pkey on role_player_address_p_54 rpa_54  (cost=0.43..457842.52 rows=1402564 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_55_pkey on role_player_address_p_55 rpa_55  (cost=0.43..457054.91 rows=1402515 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_56_pkey on role_player_address_p_56 rpa_56  (cost=0.43..436711.75 rows=1369350 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_57_pkey on role_player_address_p_57 rpa_57  (cost=0.43..460738.80 rows=1401776 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_58_pkey on role_player_address_p_58 rpa_58  (cost=0.43..466265.90 rows=1400645 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_59_pkey on role_player_address_p_59 rpa_59  (cost=0.43..442331.01 rows=1364247 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_60_pkey on role_player_address_p_60 rpa_60  (cost=0.43..444542.02 rows=1369769 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_61_pkey on role_player_address_p_61 rpa_61  (cost=0.43..460002.04 rows=1402241 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_62_pkey on role_player_address_p_62 rpa_62  (cost=0.43..440137.36 rows=1372425 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_63_pkey on role_player_address_p_63 rpa_63  (cost=0.43..440920.70 rows=1375485 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_64_pkey on role_player_address_p_64 rpa_64  (cost=0.43..440967.97 rows=1372506 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_65_pkey on role_player_address_p_65 rpa_65  (cost=0.43..441947.17 rows=1369251 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_66_pkey on role_player_address_p_66 rpa_66  (cost=0.43..452753.22 rows=1396788 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_67_pkey on role_player_address_p_67 rpa_67  (cost=0.43..439118.54 rows=1371743 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_68_pkey on role_player_address_p_68 rpa_68  (cost=0.43..48742.98 rows=1326570 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_69_pkey on role_player_address_p_69 rpa_69  (cost=0.43..458755.53 rows=1404683 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_70_pkey on role_player_address_p_70 rpa_70  (cost=0.43..48683.14 rows=1327114 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_71_pkey on role_player_address_p_71 rpa_71  (cost=0.43..48712.50 rows=1326938 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_72_pkey on role_player_address_p_72 rpa_72  (cost=0.43..48953.59 rows=1329411 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_73_pkey on role_player_address_p_73 rpa_73  (cost=0.43..48799.07 rows=1324443 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_74_pkey on role_player_address_p_74 rpa_74  (cost=0.43..48268.92 rows=1330966 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_75_pkey on role_player_address_p_75 rpa_75  (cost=0.43..48550.00 rows=1326238 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_76_pkey on role_player_address_p_76 rpa_76  (cost=0.43..48905.72 rows=1333686 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_77_pkey on role_player_address_p_77 rpa_77  (cost=0.43..48429.01 rows=1330172 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_78_pkey on role_player_address_p_78 rpa_78  (cost=0.43..48505.36 rows=1325929 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_79_pkey on role_player_address_p_79 rpa_79  (cost=0.43..48157.94 rows=1323834 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_80_pkey on role_player_address_p_80 rpa_80  (cost=0.43..48849.17 rows=1329916 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_81_pkey on role_player_address_p_81 rpa_81  (cost=0.43..48818.28 rows=1328657 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_82_pkey on role_player_address_p_82 rpa_82  (cost=0.43..48700.87 rows=1330963 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_83_pkey on role_player_address_p_83 rpa_83  (cost=0.43..48490.69 rows=1331084 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_84_pkey on role_player_address_p_84 rpa_84  (cost=0.43..48833.02 rows=1328573 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_85_pkey on role_player_address_p_85 rpa_85  (cost=0.43..49077.39 rows=1332331 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_86_pkey on role_player_address_p_86 rpa_86  (cost=0.43..48843.29 rows=1330591 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_87_pkey on role_player_address_p_87 rpa_87  (cost=0.43..48509.47 rows=1325136 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_88_pkey on role_player_address_p_88 rpa_88  (cost=0.43..48686.54 rows=1330541 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_89_pkey on role_player_address_p_89 rpa_89  (cost=0.43..48724.53 rows=1325340 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_90_pkey on role_player_address_p_90 rpa_90  (cost=0.43..48234.94 rows=1327634 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_91_pkey on role_player_address_p_91 rpa_91  (cost=0.43..48485.37 rows=1327263 width=16)
        ->  Index Only Scan using role_player_address_p_92_pkey on role_player_address_p_92 rpa_92  (cost=0.43..48517.92 rows=1329166 width=16)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=129306210.80..131157851.29 rows=370328098 width=141)
        ->  Sort  (cost=129306210.80..130232031.05 rows=370328098 width=141)
              Sort Key: eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id, rpsa.role_player_address_id
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=815.12..23438352.29 rows=370328098 width=141)
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=814.69..902.25 rows=8756 width=8)
                          Group Key: eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id
                          ->  Seq Scan on eval_source_record_1213_1214  (cost=0.00..782.95 rows=12695 width=8)
                    ->  Append  (cost=0.43..2671.60 rows=512 width=133)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_1_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_1 rpsa_1  (cost=0.43..10.42 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_2_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_2 rpsa_2  (cost=0.43..10.41 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_3_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_3 rpsa_3  (cost=0.43..10.42 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_4_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_4 rpsa_4  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_5_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_5 rpsa_5  (cost=0.43..10.41 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_6_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_6 rpsa_6  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_7_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_7 rpsa_7  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_8_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_8 rpsa_8  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_9_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_9 rpsa_9  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_10_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_10 rpsa_10  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_11_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_11 rpsa_11  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_12_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_12 rpsa_12  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_13_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_13 rpsa_13  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_14_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_14 rpsa_14  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_15_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_15 rpsa_15  (cost=0.43..10.42 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_16_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_16 rpsa_16  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_17_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_17 rpsa_17  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_18_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_18 rpsa_18  (cost=0.43..10.42 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_19_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_19 rpsa_19  (cost=0.43..10.42 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_20_pkey on role_player_standardized_address_p_20 rpsa_20  (cost=0.43..10.43 rows=2 width=133)
                                Index Cond: (role_player_id = eval_source_record_1213_1214.role_player_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using role_player_standardized_address_p_21_pkey on
```

Comment: I can't figure out what the plan here actually is trying to do.  Is the Materialize mis-indented?

Comment: Anyway you can restore an old backup to some test machine, and capture a plan from back when the query was fast?

Comment: ok, will try doing that. Thank you.

Comment: If that query that doesn't use parallel query is I/O bound, your disk is probably not strong enough.

Comment: I observered that parallel queries are running in pg_stat_activity still the query is running forever. Also tried with SET random_page_cost = 1.1 to avoid sequential scan in large table but that's also not helping.